# How to retrieve values from another class

Tags: java, class, oop, methods, tostring

I'm sorry if this question is way too long but I am currently doing a basic Programming assignment and I need some help. I will post the guidelines for the structure of the methods.
[Course Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSQm0.png) and [Student class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIPCH.png)

This is my code for the Course class:

```
public class Course{
private String courseName;
private int credit;
private double examScore;
private double assignmentScore;

/*
Default constructor
*/
public Course(){
    this.courseName = null;
    this.credit = 0;
    this.examScore = 0;
    this.assignmentScore = 0;
}

/*
Constructor with courseName and credit
*/
public Course(String courseName, int credit){
    this.courseName = courseName;
    this.credit = credit;
    this.examScore = 0;
    this.assignmentScore = 0;
}

/*
Constructor with all 4 data members
*/
public Course(String courseName, int credit, double examScore, double assignmentScore){
    this.courseName = courseName;
    this.credit = credit;
    this.examScore = examScore;
    this.assignmentScore = assignmentScore;
}

/*
Copy constructor
*/
public Course(Course anotherCourse){
    this.courseName = anotherCourse.courseName;
    this.credit = anotherCourse.credit;
    this.examScore = anotherCourse.examScore;
    this.assignmentScore = anotherCourse.assignmentScore;
}

/*
calcFinalScore constructor
*/
public double calcFinalScore(){
    double examWeight = this.examScore * 0.60;
    double assignmentWeight = this.assignmentScore * 0.40;
    
    double finalScore = examWeight + assignmentWeight;
    
    return finalScore;
}

/*
isPassed() constructor
*/
public boolean isPassed(){
    boolean isPassed = false;
    
    if(calcFinalScore() > 60){
        isPassed = true;
    }
    return isPassed;
}

/*
equals method
*/
public boolean equals(Course anotherCourse){
    return courseName.equals(anotherCourse.courseName) &&
            credit == anotherCourse.credit &&
            examScore == anotherCourse.examScore &&
            assignmentScore == anotherCourse.assignmentScore;
}
/*
toString method
*/
@Override
public String toString(){
    String output = String.format("%-17s: %s\n", "Course name", courseName);
    output += String.format("%-17s: %s\n", "Credit", credit);
    output += String.format("%-17s: %.1f\n", "Exam Score", examScore);
    output += String.format("%-17s: %.1f\n", "Assignment Score", assignmentScore);
    output += String.format("%-17s: %.1f \n", "Final Score", calcFinalScore());
    return output;
}

/*
Getters
*/
public String getCourseName(){
    return courseName;
}
public int getCredit(){
    return credit;
}
public double getExamScore(){
    return examScore;
}
public double getAssignmentScore(){
    return assignmentScore;
}

/*
Setters
*/
public void setCourseName(String courseName){
    this.courseName = courseName;
}
public void setCredit(int credit){
    this.credit = credit;
}
public void setExamScore(double examScore){
    this.examScore = examScore;
}
public void setAssignmentScore(double assignmentScore){
    this.assignmentScore = assignmentScore;
}
```

And here is my code for the Student class:

```
public class Student{
private String name;
private String gender;
private String email;
private String course1;
private String course2;
private String course3;

/*
Default constructor
*/
public Student(){
    this.name = "";
    this.gender = "";
    this.email = "";
    this.course1 = "";
    this.course2 = "";
    this.course3 = "";
}

/*
Constructor with name, gender and email
*/
public Student(String name, String gender, String email){
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.email = email;
    this.course1 = "";
    this.course2 = "";
    this.course3 = "";
}

/*
Constructor with all data members
*/
public Student(String name, String gender, String email, String course1, String course2, String course3){
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.email = email;
    this.course1 = course1;
    this.course2 = course2;
    this.course3 = course3;
}

/*
Copy constructor
*/
public Student(Student anotherStudent){
    this.name = anotherStudent.name;
    this.gender = anotherStudent.gender;
    this.email = anotherStudent.email;
    this.course1 = anotherStudent.course1;
    this.course2 = anotherStudent.course2;
    this.course3 = anotherStudent.course3;
}

/*
calcPassedCourse

public int calcPassedCourseNum(){
    
}
*/

/*
calcTotalCredit
*/

/*
isEmailValid constructor
*/
public boolean isEmailValid() {
    int atIdx = -1;
    int dotIdx = -1;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < email.length(); i++) {
        if (email.charAt(i) == '@')
            atIdx = i;
        if (email.charAt(i) == '.')
            dotIdx = i;
        
    }
    if (email.length() > 320)
        return false;
    if (email.charAt(0) == '@')
        return false;
    if (atIdx == -1 || dotIdx == -1)
        return false;
    if (atIdx > dotIdx)
        return false;
    
    return atIdx != 0 && dotIdx != email.length() - 1;
}

/*
equals method
*/
public boolean equals(Student anotherStudent){
    return name.equals(anotherStudent.name) &&
            gender.equals(anotherStudent.gender) &&
            email.equals(anotherStudent.email) &&
            course1.equals(anotherStudent.course1) &&
            course2.equals(anotherStudent.course2) &&
            course3.equals(anotherStudent.course3);
}

/*
toString
*/
@Override
public String toString(){
    String output = String.format("%-17s: %s\n", "Name", name);
    output += String.format("%-17s: %s\n", "Gender", gender);
    output += String.format("%-17s: %s\n", "Email", email);
    output += String.format("\n%-18s %-25s %-7s %s \n", "Course", "Name", "Credit", "Score");
    output += String.format("%s \n", "----------------------------------------------------------");
    output += String.format("%-17s: %s \n", "Course 1", course1);
    output += String.format("%-17s: %s \n", "Course 2", course2);
    output += String.format("%-17s: %s \n", "Course 3", course3);
    //output += String.format("-17s: %.1f", "Passed Courses");
    //output += String.format("-17s: %.1f", "Total Credits")
    return output;
}

/*
Getters
*/
public String getName(){
    return name;
}
public String getGender(){
    return gender;
}
public String getEmail(){
    return email;
}
public String getCourse1(){
    return course1;
}
public String getCourse2(){
    return course2;
}
public String getCourse3(){
    return course3;
}

/*
Setters
*/
public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
public void setGender(String gender){
    this.gender = gender;
}
public void setEmail(String email){
    this.email = email;
}
public void setCourse1(String course1){
    this.course1 = course1;
}
public void setCourse2(String course2){
    this.course2 = course2;
}
public void setCourse3(String course3){
    this.course3 = course3;
}
```

What I would like to know is how to initiate the calcPassedCourseNum() and the calcTotalCredit() methods by using the values that were input into a Course object.

For example, in the Student toString() method, I would need to print the credits and score that the student has got but I have no way of retrieving those values.

I'm not sure if I am not understanding or if the guidelines are unclear.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Was the `Student` class given to you? If not, I think your course1, course2 and course3 need to be `Course` objects. Not `String` objects.

Comment: No, the Student class was not given to me, I have created it myself. If I create 3 course objects within the Student class, then I should be able to reference them?

Comment: Yes. But again, it depends on how you write them in your Student class constructor. Basically, you will have to call `Course()` constructor in your Student class constructor for the 3 courses.

Comment: Since your Task 2 instructions state, that your Student class should also have data members course1, course2 and course3 (all of Course class) AND that your Student class should also have a class constructor with all six data members, it is probably expected from you, that you populate course1, course2 and course3 data members with values received through the constructor. It is not entirely clear how to populate them when other constructors are used, however. Probably just keeping course1-3 as null, but on that part the instructions are not clear.

Comment: Since the Task 1 states that the Course class should also have a default constructor, that would be something that could be used in Student default constructor (point a) and in the Student constructor with name, gender and email (point b). Doing that would ensure that data members course1-3 are always initialised (never null, if you also don't allow nulls to slip through in the 3rd constructor), so the implementations of the calc* methods then just use the data members.

Comment: Alright, I have managed to get things working by creating Course objects within the Student class. The rest is sort of falling into place. Thank you guys for your help, it is greatly appreciated!